# Haskell: How to make a type an instance of two typeclasses?

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to make `Level` an instance of `Eq` and `Ord`?

```
instance Eq Ord Level where
    compare First Second = LT
    ...
```

I've tried this

```
instance (Ord, Eq) => Level where ...
```

But I've got an error

```
‘compare’ is not a (visible) method of class ‘Level’
```

I know I can use `deriving (Eq)` on my `data Level`. But I cannot change my `data`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use two instances

```
instance Eq Level where
   x == y = ...
instance Ord Level where
   compare x y = ...
```

Alternatively, use the [standalone deriving extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/deriving.html#stand-alone-deriving):

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
...       -- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ must be at the top of the file
deriving instance (Eq Level)
deriving instance (Ord Level)
```

Comment: @chi, ah, missed it. Sorry.